How to know when a control's visible state has changed?
The visible state of a control may change depending on the visible state of its parent control, how do I know this?
For example
Display display = Display.getDefault() ;
Shell shell = new Shell( display ) ;
shell.setSize( 400, 600 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout( SWT.VERTICAL ) ) ;

Composite composite = new  Composite( shell, SWT.NONE ) ;
composite.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
Button test = new Button( composite, SWT.NONE ) ;
test.setText( "test" ) ;

composite.addListener( SWT.Show, e -> System.out.println( "Composite Show" ) ) ;
composite.addListener( SWT.Hide, e -> System.out.println( "Composite Hide" ) ) ;
test.addListener( SWT.Show, e -> System.out.println( "Button Show" ) ) ;
test.addListener( SWT.Hide, e -> System.out.println( "Button Hide" ) ) ;

Button btn = new Button( shell, SWT.TOGGLE ) ;
btn.setText( "Show / Hide" ) ;
btn.addListener( SWT.Selection, e -> {
    composite.setVisible( btn.getSelection() ) ;
    System.out.println( test.isVisible() ) ;
} ) ;

shell.open() ;
while ( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if ( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
        display.sleep() ;
     }
}


I can't get the Button's Show/Hide event.

The Show/Hide event is only sent on the Composite. Looking at the source there is no attempt to propogate the event to its children.

Yes, but is there any other way to know the change of visible state from the child Control level?

Not that I know off, but I have never had a need to respond to visibility changes. You would have to listen to the Composite event and go though the children of the composite.

What would knowing the state of visibility, setting aside that it could be partially visible in different amounts ms to ms, let you do?
